# strange Python version-dependent behavior with writing sorted output using heapq.merge

Tags: python

Some of the gsutil users have reported a failure when running gsutil rsync, which I've tracked down to being apparently a Python 2.7.8-specific problem: we write sorted lists of the source and destination directories being synchronized in binary mode ('w+b'), and then read those lists back in, also in binary mode ('rb'). This works fine under Python 2.6.x and Python 2.7.3, but under Python 2.7.8 the output ends up in a garbled-looking binary format, which then doesn't parse correctly when being read back in.

If I switch the output to use 'w+' mode instead the problem goes away. But (a) I think I do want to write in binary mode, since these files can contain Unicode, and (b) I'd like to understand why this is a Python version-dependent problem.

Does anyone have any ideas about why this might be happening?

FYI, I tried to reproduce this problem with a short program that just writes a file in binary mode and reads it back in binary mode, but the problem doesn't repro with this program. I'm wondering if there might be something about the heapq.merge implementation that changed in Python 2.7.8 that might explain this problem (we sort in batches, and the individual sorted files are fine; its the output from heapq.merge that gets garbled in binary mode under Python 2.7.8).

Any suggsetions/thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing reading and writing to the `w+b` file *without seeks or flushes between the two modes*? If you are writing Unicode values, consider using `io.open()` file objects and have Python encode to a given encoding (say UTF-8) by the file object.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn - I was mixing reading and writing but I flush and seek(0) after writing and before reading. However, switching to io.open() and not using binary mode and instead using encoding='UTF8' appears to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if the file object hasn't properly been flushed or no seek has been done between a read and write action, or vice versa. A binary object would be more susceptible to this as the OS won't be doing newline translation either. At a C level undefined behaviour can be triggered and uninitialised memory is then read or written. There is a Python issue about this at http://bugs.python.org/issue1394612.

Why this changed in a Python minor version is interesting however, and if you have a reproducible case you should definitively report it to the [Python project issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org/).

If you are just writing Unicode, then *encode* that Unicode to a UTF encoding; you do **not** need to use a binary file mode for that as UTF-8 will never use newline bytes in other codepoints.

Alternatively, use the [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to open a Unicode-aware file object for your data.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried to create a small program to repro the Python version-dependent problem, but it didn't repro. FYI the code is at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/gslib/commands/rsync.py, and the change I submitted based on your suggestion is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/commit/11bfbd708eec93c4782dcac8550a79cb6da41510